# Shopware 6, administration, order list, change order date format

Tags: shopware

everybody. I have a small task on unknown product. Need to change date format at order list in Shopware 6.
Now it looks like:
**22/06/21, 22:23**

I want to show date only, without time.

In SW docs found [guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/customizing-components)

In SW source found template for order list screen:
shopware\vendor\shopware\administration\Resources\app\administration\src\module\sw-order\page\sw-order-list\sw-order-list.html.twig

with code for date column:

```
{% block sw_order_list_grid_columns_order_date %}
    <template #column-orderDateTime="{ item }">
        {{ item.orderDateTime | date({hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}) }}
    </template>
{% endblock %}
```

In my plugin added new component:
plugins\MyPlugin\src\Resources\app\administration\src\core\component\sw-order-list-override

with new template "sw-order-list.html.twig":

```
{% block sw_order_list_grid_columns_order_date %}
    {{ item.orderDateTime | format_date('medium') }}
{% endblock %}
```

and with new "index.js":

```
import template from './sw-order-list.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.override('sw-order-list', {
  template
});
```

Into "plugins\MyPlugin\src\Resources\app\administration\src\main.js" added:
`import './core/component/sw-order-list-override/';`

At SW host rebuilded administration, reloaded order screen list in browser and screen was changed BUT not as expected.
Now order date looks like ISO date:
**2021-07-13T00:08:21.413+00:00**

What is wrong in my code?

I've even added something like this in override template

```
{% block sw_order_list_grid_columns_order_date %}
    TEST TEXT
{% endblock %}
```

But did not see "TEST TEXT" in order date column, but the same ISO format date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have learned, the administration frontend of SW6 does not implement the complete twig functionality but a slim one. You can only use twig functions, not the filters, unfortunately.

What did the trick for me was leaving the date function without any parameters:

```
{{ item.orderDateTime|date({hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}) }}
{# results in dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii (or another date format depending on your configuration) #}

{{ item.orderDateTime|date() }}
{# results in dd.mm.yyyy without time #}
```

The ISO formatted date you get is just the item.orderDateTime without any filters, as the filter you have given won't work here.